Problem with barchart labels when using scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
When I use scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) in my ggplot horizontal bar chart, the first bar label disappears. below you can finde the code used.
Could you please help me with it?
Thanks
options(scipen = 999)

data_test <- tribble(
  ~name, ~cost1, ~cost2, ~totalCost,
  "John", 46000000, 90000000, 136000000,
  "Martin", 10000, 95000000, 95100000,
  "Michael", 15100000, 60000000, 75100000,
  "Dave", 68000000, 1000000, 690000000,
  "Dan", 42600000, 16000000, 58600000
)

ggp <- data_test %>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, totalCost)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(totalCost, name, fill = totalCost)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.6, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = 0, 0.05)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "#24336a", low = "#2296cf") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale())(totalCost)),
            size = 3,
            hjust = -0.1,
            color = "black")

ggp



Have you tried manually increasing limits of x scale?
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits=c(0, 800000000))

It works perfectly! Thanks

See https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html#zooming. coord_cartesian(xlim = ...., clip = "off") might be more appropriate here, as it doesn't filter out data beyond the range.

Why not use scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))
